# Why won't this work? C++

Tags: c++

I've recently started learning the basics of C++ by going through the  book written on the language by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I've ran into a problem at the section where he goes over creating structures using Vector.

The error produced says that the variable or field 'vector_init' declared void,
'Vector' was not declared in this scope, 'v' was not declared in this scope, and expected primary-expression before 'int'

```
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct Vector {
        int sz;                             // number of elements
        double* elem;                       // pointer to elements 
    };

    Vector my_first_vector;

    return 0;
}
void vector_init(Vector& v, int s)
{

    v.elem = new double[s];                 // allocate an array of s doubles
    v.sz = s;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future question, you might want to consider a more descriptive title. Also, I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Comment: And never ever do using namespace std; NEVER.

Answer (score 5):

The error message means exactly what it says; you've declared the struct `Vector` within the scope of `main`. Outside of `main`, no other functions know what `Vector` is. To fix this, move your definition of `struct Vector` to outside the `main` block.

Answer (score 2):

You should move :

```
struct Vector {
    int sz;                             // number of elements
    double* elem;                       // pointer to elements 
};
```

outside and above `main`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code... below is a fix that allows it to compile: you need to declare the `struct Vector` outside the `main`.

```
using namespace std; // <~ this is bad practice. Try to not use it (or minimize its scope)

struct Vector {
   int sz;                             // number of elements
   double* elem;                       // pointer to elements 
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    Vector my_first_vector;

    return 0;
}

void vector_init(Vector& v, int s)
{
    v.elem = new double[s];                 // allocate an array of s doubles (also leaks memory)
    v.sz = s;
}
```

I hope you plan to write a `vector_clear` method which will `delete [] v.elem`. Otherwise your program is going to leak memory.